# How to handle multiple data sources in one WCF Domain Service?

Tags: wcf, ado.net, service, dns

I'm working on creating a WCF Domain Service which at the moment provides access to a database. I created the Entity Model, added the DomainService (LinqToEntitiesDomainService) and everything works so far.

But there are cases when my data doesn't come from the DB but somewhere else (for instance an uploaded file). Are there any best practices out there how to handle this different data sources properly without resorting to writing two completely different data providers? It would be great to access both types with one interface. Is there already something I can use?

I'm fairly new to this so any advice apart from that is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How many cases where the data comes from a file? How many files? How will you know if a file is there? Are you going to poll the directory? what format are the files? (XML support is possible)

Microsoft's documentation suggests that you can create a custom host endpoint, but I don't know what limitations there are.

Comment: The format will be XML. The file will be a dump of a part of the database. The user will explicitly choose to use the file and not the database. I think it will be used very frequently.